# Calculating percentages in SQL command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to refactor my code. I was returning all rows, and filtering the result set with php, but this is quickly becoming a performance issue.

**Current code:**

```
$percentOff = 80;

$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Available=1 AND Merchant='Amazon'"); //Selects all from DB. VERY slow

            $finalResults = array();
            //Limit the results returned
            foreach($rows as $row){
                $totalSavings = ($row["LowestNewPrice"] - $row["LowestUsedPrice"]) / $row["LowestNewPrice"] * 100;
                if($totalSavings >= $percentOff){
                    $finalResults[] = $row;
                }
            }
```

**Refactored SQL:**

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Available=1 AND Merchant='Amazon' AND (LowestNewPrice - LowestUsedPrice / LowestNewPrice * 100) >= ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $percentOff, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This returns ALL from `products`. I only want to return results that are >= 80. Where did I go wrong?

**DB**

```
| LowestNewPrice           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| LowestUsedPrice          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
```

Comment: Depending on scale, it's probably worthwhile to cache `(LowestNewPrice - LowestUsedPrice / LowestNewPrice * 100)` in a column. As a quick guess, this might be the result of an integer division at `LowestUsedPrice / LowestNewPrice`. That depends on your table schema.

Comment: Caching is in the plans, but I need to get this simple fix in place first. I'm not too familiar with MySQL, how would integer division affect the statement? PHP is handling it right now, it's just slow

Comment: Interger division round down to the nearest integer. So e.g. 48/50 * 100 is evaluated as (48/50) * 100 = 0 * 100 = 0. Whereas 100 * 48/50 evaluates as (100 * 48) / 50 = 4800 / 50 = 96.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing brackets around `LowestNewPrice - LowestUsedPrice`
2. As Luke mentioned, you may also be running into integer division. Multiply with 100 **before** you divide.